# is it possible to count the number of actions inside of a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am not sure if 'action' is the right word to use, but suppose you have a method that looks something like this:

```
def schedule_jobs
  User.schedule!      
  Activity.schedule!      
  Event.schedule!
  Notify.schedule! 
end
```

What I am looking for is to run some kind of function on the schedule_jobs method that will return 4.

I want it because I will create a test that says makes sure 4 jobs were scheduled, however, that would require me to manually change 4 to 5 when I add `Report.schedule!` next week.

Comment: What if in the methods you add a `+= 1` counter? And then at the end see what the count is. That way you can verify the action succeeded as well.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If your test adapts itself to always pass, then what is the point of the test?

Comment: @Drenmi i am going to check if the jobs have been added to the background job queue.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss Then why don't you write a test for precisely what you just said? Testing that "the number of times a method was called == the number of scheduled jobs" is an absurdly fuzzy test! I could make it pass with completely the wrong code!

Comment: Tests that "always pass" are useless. If the behaviour changes, you should *want* your test to fail.

Comment: @TomLord I am going to count the number of jobs that are going to be scheduled (x) and then add a test that says (were x jobs scheduled?)... this will be on top of other tests... otherwise, if someone adds another job to be scheduled without a test, how do we test for that?

Comment: @TomLord otherwise, say i have 4 tests, (were jobs # 1/2/3/4 scheduled?).. now someone adds job #5.. ?? i need a test to fail for that.

Comment: Okay, then do exactly that! Write a test to say `expect(number_of_scheduled_jobs).to eq 4`. And if someone adds job #5 to that method, the test fails. I don't see any need for a mechanism of *programatically determining* how many jobs were supposed to get scheduled.

Comment: This is a classic example of an XY problem: You're looking for an answer to the wrong question. A better question might, perhaps, be: How do I determine the number of `ActiveJob` jobs that got scheduled?

Comment: @TomLord good point

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss what if you decide to extract some of the method calls into another method? A test that is counting method invocations will fail, because it is testing the _implementation_ (i.e. _how_ the method is working). Instead you should test the _behaviour_ (i.e. _what_ the method is doing). Regarding testing for changes: RSpec comes with a [change matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-7/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher), e.g. `expect { schedule_jobs }.to change { scheduled_jobs_count }.by(4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing something like:

```
class Foo

  JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE = %w(
    User
    Activity
    Event
    Notify
  ).freeze

  def schedule_jobs
    self.class::JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE.each do |job_to_schedule|
      job_to_schedule.constantize.schedule!
    end
  end

end
```

Then, you could always interrogate `Foo::JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE` to see how many jobs you expected to schedule.

**Following up on the comments:**

> The call to #constantize is also not needed, as you can just reference the constants in the array instead of using strings.

Assume I have a class `Foo` like this:

```
class Foo

  JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE = %w(
    Baz
  ).freeze

  def schedule_jobs
    JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE.each do |job_to_schedule|
      puts job_to_schedule.class.name
      job_to_schedule.schedule!
    end
  end

end
```

And that I have a class, `Baz` like this:

```
class Baz

  class << self 

    def schedule!
      puts "scheduled!"
    end

  end

end
```

If I call `Foo.new.schedule_jobs` then I get:

```
> Foo.new.schedule_jobs
String
NoMethodError: undefined method `schedule!' for "Baz":String
```

As can be seen, `job_to_schedule` is a `String` (because, that's what `%w()` does, creates an array of `String`s). So, I get the `NoMethodError` because `String` doesn't respond to `schedule!`.

If, however, I include `constantize`, like this:

```
class Foo

  JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE = %w(
    Baz
  ).freeze

  def schedule_jobs
    JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE.each do |job_to_schedule|
      puts job_to_schedule.class.name
      job_to_schedule.constantize.schedule!
    end
  end

end
```

Then, when calling `Foo.new.schedule_jobs`, I get:

```
> Foo.new.schedule_jobs
String
scheduled!
```

So, the call to `#constantize` *is* needed.

Now, I *could* do this:

```
class Foo

  JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE = [
    Baz
  ].freeze

  def schedule_jobs
    JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE.each do |job_to_schedule|
      puts job_to_schedule.class.name
      job_to_schedule.schedule!
    end
  end

end
```

In which case, if I do `Foo.new.schedule_jobs`, I get:

```
> Foo.new.schedule_jobs
Class
scheduled!
```

And all is good.

> self.class is not needed – instance methods can directly access constants.

Assume I have a class `Bar` like this:

```
class Bar < Foo
end
```

If I do `Bar.new.schedule_jobs`, then I get:

```
> Bar.new.schedule_jobs
String
scheduled!
```

So, the comment is correct.

> referencing the constants in the array could trigger Ruby's auto loading mechanism which might not be desired. I'd use symbols.

If I have:

```
class Foo

  JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE = [
    :baz
  ].freeze

  def schedule_jobs
    JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE.each do |job_to_schedule|
      puts job_to_schedule.class.name
      job_to_schedule.schedule!
    end
  end

end
```

Then when I do `Foo.new.schedule_jobs`, I get:

```
> Foo.new.schedule_jobs
Symbol
NoMethodError: undefined method `schedule!' for :baz:Symbol
```

As expected. And, naturally, this doesn't work either:

```
class Foo

  JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE = [
    :baz
  ].freeze

  def schedule_jobs
    JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE.each do |job_to_schedule|
      puts job_to_schedule.class.name
      job_to_schedule.constantize.schedule!
    end
  end

end
```

When I do `Foo.new.schedule_jobs`, I get:

```
> Foo.new.schedule_jobs
Symbol
NoMethodError: undefined method `constantize' for :baz:Symbol
```

Because I'm trying to constantize a symbol. I *could* do:

```
class Foo

  JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE = [
    :baz
  ].freeze

  def schedule_jobs
    JOBS_TO_SCHEDULE.each do |job_to_schedule|
      puts job_to_schedule.class.name
      job_to_schedule.to_s.camelize.constantize.schedule!
    end
  end

end
```

In which case, when I do `Foo.new.schedule_jobs`, I get:

```
> Foo.new.schedule_jobs
Symbol
scheduled!
```

And all is good again. (But, I had to do `.to_s.camelize`, which is some typing I'd rather avoid.)

Comment: `self.class` is not needed – instance methods can directly access constants.

Comment: In this particular instance, you are precisely correct.

Comment: The call to `#constantize` is also not needed, as you can just reference the constants in the array instead of using strings.

Comment: @Drenmi referencing the constants in the array could trigger Ruby's auto loading mechanism which might not be desired. I'd use symbols.

Comment: I'd use `JOBS = [:Bar]` and `JOBS.each { |job| Object.const_get(job).schedule! }`

Comment: Interesting. Is that a preference? Or, is there a specific benefit?

Comment: Kind of, I prefer pure Ruby solutions. `:Bar` is the way Ruby represents constants (try `Object.constants`) and `const_get` is a built-in method, too.

Comment: Excellent. I can appreciate steering towards pure Ruby. Thank you for the insight! Learn something new every day...

Comment: Not sure how referencing a class constant directly is somehow not "pure Ruby". Do you also do `Object.const_get(:User).find(...)`? The autoloading is an interesting point. I think since that needs to be registered explicitly, the user would have some idea what they're doing. (Although this is not always the case.) One downside of using symbols or strings is you lose all features of your editor or IDE relating to refactoring, finding usages, etc.